# Performance testing of HTML5/cs/js pages in phonegap

Tags: performance, html, cordova

I'm a tester and our company is planning to build an app in HTML5/CSS/JS, jquery mobile and deploy on iPhone and android using phonegap.

I was wondering how would I test performance of the app on these platforms? Specifically performance of the rendering, user response times, dynamic data binding?

Is there a tool that can measure performance of the above? Can I use automation?

Appreciate your answers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Weinre](http://people.apache.org/~pmuellr/weinre/). But the metrics are limited and still a lot of manual steps involved. Your best bet is to write your own instrumentation and JS based reporting.